# Segmentation fault using dlib with gpu

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gpu, dlib

I just installed dlib and I created one project with the [cpu introduction example](http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction_ex.cpp.html) and another one with the [gpu introduction example](http://dlib.net/dnn_introduction2_ex.cpp.html). the first one is compiled and executed on my computer and the second one is compiled and executed on a linux server to use the Nvidia GC. For the cpu example I can compile and execute without any problem. For the gpu example, I can compile without any problem but when I execute it, the initialization is ok but when the network is training I have the first epoch done properly and then I have a segmentation fault. The method used is `trainer.train_one_step(mini_batch_samples, mini_batch_labels);`

I also tried to train a network using the cpu and then to import it to the gpu example using the deserialize method but I also have a segmentation fault when it tried to do the prediction. The method used for the prediction is `std::vector<unsigned long> predicted_labels = tnet(training_images);`

I have this problem even without changing anything in the example code so I don't understand why I have this segfault. If someone can help me I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for this question but just in case this really stupid mistake happens to someone, I didn't installed the latest version of dlib and this was causing troubles. After installing the latest version it's working properly...